# I have two files LOGIN.py and LOGINCLICK.py. How to open LOGIN.py file from LOGINCLICK.py by clicking a button?

Tags: python, pyqt5

LOGIN.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_LOGIN_PAGE(object):
    def setupUi(self, LOGIN_PAGE):
        LOGIN_PAGE.setObjectName("LOGIN_PAGE")
        LOGIN_PAGE.resize(1909, 995)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(LOGIN_PAGE)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 220, 501, 571))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Cambria Math")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.frame.setFont(font)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n""background:rgb(255, 250, 175);\n""border-radius:30px;\n"
        "}\n""\n""QLineEdit{\n""border-radius:10px;\n""}\n""\n""QPushButton{\n""background:#03a9f4;\n"
        "border-radius:10px;}")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 360, 441, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Cambria")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 480, 241, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gill Sans MT")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 260, 441, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Cambria Math")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 441, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Cambria Math")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 231, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Cambria Math")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 210, 231, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Cambria Math")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        LOGIN_PAGE.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(LOGIN_PAGE)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        LOGIN_PAGE.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(LOGIN_PAGE)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(LOGIN_PAGE)

    def retranslateUi(self, LOGIN_PAGE):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        LOGIN_PAGE.setWindowTitle(_translate("LOGIN_PAGE", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("LOGIN_PAGE", "LOGIN"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("LOGIN_PAGE", "Forget Password"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("LOGIN_PAGE", "PASSWORD"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("LOGIN_PAGE", "USERNAME"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("LOGIN_PAGE", "USERNAME :"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("LOGIN_PAGE", "PASSWORD :"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    LOGIN_PAGE = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_LOGIN_PAGE()
    ui.setupUi(LOGIN_PAGE)
    LOGIN_PAGE.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

LOGINCLICK.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(505, 256)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, -1, 501, 251))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n""background:rgb(248, 255, 185);}\n""\n""QPushButton{\n"
        "background:#03a9f4;\n""border-radius:10px;}")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 90, 151, 51))
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")
        self.pushButton1_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton1_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 90, 151, 51))
        self.pushButton1_2.setObjectName("pushButton1_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LOGIN"))
        self.pushButton1_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "REGISTRATION"))
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How to switch from LOGINCLICK.py to LOGIN.py by clicking a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, and this is more a matter of concept, you're not going to "switch" between those files, but between the instances of the classes that are in those files.

Second, you should create a file that acts as a "main" script, which is the file that you'll actually run from python; this is a general rule for programs that use multiple files as "modules", and is almost mandatory for PyQt when using files generated by `pyuic`; note that you should also **never** modify the contents of those files, but import them as python modules (read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)).

Recreate the files with pyuic, then create a new file that will look like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from LOGINCLICK import Ui_MainWindow
from LOGIN import Ui_LOGIN_PAGE

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.showLogin)

    def showLogin(self):
        self.loginWindow = LoginWindow()
        self.loginWindow.show()


class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_LOGIN_PAGE):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now, some suggestions:

- avoid fixed geometries in any case, and use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead (like QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout or QVBoxLayout) so that the contents of the windows will always adjust to the available size, otherwise some of the widgets might become unaccessible if the user resizes the window to a smaller size than you decided (there are also other reasons for this, but this is the most important);
- don't use uppercase names for files or variables; read more about naming conventions in the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/);
- a login window should probably be "modal" (shown over the current windows and avoiding interaction with them until the login window is closed); you can use a QDialog for this: from Designer create a new empty *dialog*, copy the elements of your current login form and paste them to the new dialog (or select all of them and use ctrl+drag), save and generate the file with pyuic, then change the above code considering the following modifications:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    #...

    def showLogin(self):
        self.loginWindow = LoginWindow(self)
        self.loginWindow.exec_()

class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_LOGIN_PAGE):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```